# Prove a function is onto if its domain is a Cartesian product

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I've been working on this problem:

> Suppose the function $f:\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ is defined by $f(n,m)=2nm-1$. Is this function onto?

After a while, I figured out that $4$ can't be output from the function $f$, and then I realized that this function can't output any even numbers either. It seems that because the function follows the formula $2k-1$ for odd numbers, that's why it only produces odd numbers.

Because of that, I know that this function can't be onto. However, I don't know where to begin to write an abstract proof of this. I could normally do this if it were for a domain that wasn't a Cartesian product, but I haven't been able to find examples on how this is usually done.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by an abstract proof? Your argument is solid. Given $n$, $m$,  $f(m,n)=2mn-1$ is odd so there can be no $(m,n)\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ such that $f(m,n)=0$.

Comment: I think I'm slightly paranoid that my teacher wants a formally written proof somehow. I just don't know if writing as much as I did is fine for my discrete math class. I constantly notice that a lot of proofs start usually start with "suppose" this, "assume" that, "let" this be this, and "write this" like that. It feels wrong to do it any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ of the form $k = 2nm$ with $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ is even. Thus $k' = 2nm - 1$ is always odd. Therefore $f: \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}, (n,m) \mapsto 2nm-1$ is not onto.

Comment: This was already said in the post.

Comment: This is structured in a nicer and more compact way, it's more or less what I was asking for! I thought I needed to go more abstract for a formal proof, but this works!

Comment: Glad i could help. You basically wrote down all it took, i just rephrased it.